# find command exec option

Tags: command-line, unix, bash, find

I'm trying to use the **+** option of find exec instead of xargs. However, I can't seem to get it to work.  I feel I must be missing something obvious here.

Example:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep "@author" {} + \;
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

On the other hand, this works:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep "@author" {}  \;
```

as does this:

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs  grep "@author"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need \; together with +

Comment: find . -name "*.java" -exec grep "@author" {} +

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier just to use `find -print0 | xargs --null -I XXX do_something XXX`. Let `find` to the `find`ing and `xargs` do the, er, other stuff.

Comment: If you use `find -print0`, you need `-0` for xargs.

Comment: `-0` is the short version of `--null`.